# PHP Stan error Service 'errorFormatter.github' Multiple services of type PHPStan\Command\ErrorFormatter\TableErrorFormatter

Tags: error, magento2.3.4, phpstan

> I am facing an error after running below command:

```
vendor/bin/phpstan analyse -c dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Php/_files/phpstan/phpstan.neon app/code/Vendor/CustomModule --level 0
```

> Error:

```
In Resolver.php line 442:

  Service 'errorFormatter.github' (type of PHPStan\Command\ErrorFormatter\GithubErrorFormatter): Multiple services of type PHPStan\Command\ErrorFormatter\TableErrorForma
  tter found: errorFormatter.filtered, errorFormatter.table (needed by $tableErrorformatter in __construct())


In Autowiring.php line 50:

  Multiple services of type PHPStan\Command\ErrorFormatter\TableErrorFormatter found: errorFormatter.filtered, errorFormatter.table
```

[image]

> Please guide me to resolve this error, here i am using Magento 2.3.4
> verions and PHP 7.2.31

Comment: Have you tried this before the line of error and see? `/* @phpstan-ignore-next-line */` This will not fix the issue but will ignore, so that no error will display when phpstan command is run.

Comment: @rukrlf, no not yet, where to comment this line of code. please help me.

Comment: Try it just before Resolver.php line 442 and Autowiring.php line 50.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box I will recommend to use:
[phpstan-magento](https://github.com/bitExpert/phpstan-magento)

Your command should look like:

```
vendor/bin/phpstan analyse -c vendor/bitexpert/phpstan-magento/extension.neon app/code/Vendor/CustomModule --level 0
```